# SQL MS ACCESS Editor is Wonky for Union ALL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, union-all

I've never experienced this issue before and it is preventing me from completing my task. I will provide a few examples, when I hit the space key it will add characters (usually the preceding characters).  If I write the letter L, it will write out LDA, or something similar.

My insert key is disabled. The Version I'm working in is 2007-2016. I should also note that this is a brand new PC provided by the City I'm employed by.

I am at my wits end here and would appreciate any help.

I've also tried three different keyboards....

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is, you might be talking about intellisense or alike.

Comment: Essentially, I explained it.  When trying to edit my SQL, if I hit the Enter Key, it will not only advance the code to the next line, but it will also delete some of the previous text.  When I hit the space bar when trying to fix something, it will add characters.  I have no other way to explain this.  It's mind boggling.

Comment: Indeed, the query editor misbehaves sometimes when typing into it; overwrites existing characters, the cursor position is incorrect etc. I usually use an external editor, like notepad++, and then I copy the query to the SQL view directly. I'm using office 365.

Comment: I always used notepad to write, I'll give ++ a try and see what happens.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Notepad++ gives you the option to select the language (SQL in this case) which assists in code formatting. Much easier to work with than notepad.

Comment: Works so far!  Thanks again!